Detecting expired login session and loging customer out
I have OpenCart 3.0.4.0 (Github 3.0.x.x install) and everything seems to work as expected.  The OpenCart store is integrated into a broader site and I am trying to keep the OpenCart login session in sync with the broader site login session (I use $_SESSION[] variables to communicate between OpenCart pages and other site pages).  All is well if a customer logs in or out of OpenCart - I can detect that and carry login information across to the rest of the site.  However, I can not seem to seem to spot where in the code a session is determined to be expired and the user is logged out. I see that session expiration times are kept in the oc_session database table, I see where these times are loaded and refreshed, but can not see where a customer session is terminated and the customer is logged ot (so that I can capture this signal and log out the customer form the rest of the site as well).
Will appreciate any help.  Thank you.
I looked through the code and see that gc_maxlifetime is set in php.ini, that system/library/cart/session/db.php associates an expiration time with a session and writes to oc_session, but I don;t see where the session is determined to be expired and the user is logged out. I checked all the places where customer->logout() is called, and I don't see any connection to session expiration.

Answering my own question, in case it is of benefit to somebody else.
Never could find the place in the OC code where a session expiration is detected and the current customer is logged out.  However, was able to find another solution by editing the catalog/controller/common/header.php (PHP code that runs at the top of each OC page) and adding the following code snippet just before the return() statement:
if (! $this->customer->isLogged()) {
    unset($_SESSION['customer']);   
}

This will trigger any time no customer is logged in (including if the session has recently expired and the customer has been logged out) and will log out the customer form the site in which OC is embedded.
Will welcome a more elegant answer, but in the meantime this works well.

using
if (! $this->customer->isLogged()) {
unset($_SESSION['customer']);
}   

is not a good way to deal with sessions as it is only used to check if the customer is logged in or not
so if the user is just a guest you won't be able to deal with the session being expired
I think you can use the "getId" method from the session class is a better approach
$session_id = $this->session->getId();

use it to get the session id and compare it to the session id you already have
if it is not identical that means the old session has expired and new session is active
